# Shuffle arrays of strings in JavaScript with repeated elements that are at least two elements apart

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I have two arrays of strings:

```
var array1 = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6"];
var array2 = ["word7", "word8"];
```

I need to concatenate these arrays into a new array and shuffle the elements in a random order. However, the elements from `array2` should repeat appear twice in this new array, and the repeats of a given element must be at least two elements apart from each other.

Here's an example result that satisfies these conditions:

```
["word7", "word3", "word8", "word7", "word1", "word4", "word6", "word8", "word5", "word2"];
```

All the elements are in a random order, and the repeated elements have at least two other elements between them. How can I write a function (using no extra libraries, preferably) that creates a randomly ordered array that satisfies the above conditions? I've tried extending standard permutation algorithms (e.g. Fisher-Yates) but I'm tripping over the implementation as I'm not very familiar with JS.

Any help greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: `the repeats of a given element must be at least two elements apart from each other.` Can the delimiter element repeat? Such as `word7,word1, word1,word1`

Comment: "two elements apart" as in "there must be at least two elements between" or there "there must be at least on element between"?

Comment: @derpirscher "at least two elements between" is the right interpretation - sorry for the lack of clarity; edited my answer to fix this

Comment: @ikhvjs no, they should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would probably be doing it in two steps.

1. Shuffle `array1` with a standard fisher-yates algorithm.
2. Insert the elements at random positions satisfying the conditions.

Ie something like the following (I assume, you can implement fisher yates, thus I didn't include it here and just made an (unshuffled) copy of the array)

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let array2 = [8,9]

let rand = (n) => Math.floor(Math.random()*n);

//let shuffled = fisheryates(array1);
let shuffled = array1.slice(); //just make a copy of the array
    
while (array2.length) {
  let e = array2.splice(rand(array2.length), 1)[0];
  let i1 = shuffled.length == 2 
    ? 0 
    : rand(shuffled.length + 1);
  let i2 = 0;
  do {
    i2 = shuffled.length == 2 
     ? 2 
     : rand(shuffled.length + 1);
  }
  while (Math.abs(i1 - i2) < 2)

  if (i1 < i2) {
    shuffled.splice(i2, 0, e);
    shuffled.splice(i1, 0, e);
  } else {
    shuffled.splice(i1, 0, e);
    shuffled.splice(i2, 0, e);
  }
}
    
console.log(shuffled)
```

How does it work:

Iterating over all elements from `array2` in random order

- you get a random index for inserting the first element. If the `shuffled` has only 2 elements, the only valid indexes are 0 and 2 (because that's the only way, that there are at least two elements in between). I'm using `shuffled.length + 1` here, because that allows to insert the element also at the end of the array.
- Then you need to find another index, which is at least two elements away from the first index. The easiest (but not necessarily the fastest) method is just to try until an index is found.
- When inserting the element in the array, you have to insert the bigger index first, because otherwise the upper element will be at the wrong position.

If `array1` does only have one element, you need at least two elements in `array2` to be able to generate a valid output, but you can do that by hand as as special case.

```
let array1 = ['a']
let array2 = ['x', 'y', ...]
let shuffled = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'x', 'y'] //or yxayx
```

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly the kind of thing I wanted to do, but couldn't quite figure out the syntax for. Huge thanks!

Comment: Oops, there was a small error, which prohibited elements from `array2` to be inserted at the very first position in the array ... In `Math.random()*(shuffled.length +1)` there were  some parenthesis missing. But it's probalby clearer to make a dedicated `rand()` function anyways